# ASP.Net MVC3 display sql output in webgrid

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using ASP.Net MVC3 with MySQL .

Trying to figure out beast way to return sql result from controller to view and display output using webgrid help class.

tried following its not working.

**Controler code**

```
data = New DataTable
da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + tables.SelectedItem.ToString(), conn)
cb = New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
da.Fill(data)
ViewData("grid") = data
```

**View Code**

```
@Code   
    Dim grid As New WebGrid(ViewData("grid"))
End Code
@grid.GetHtml()
```

please correct me, what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks
SR

Comment: What is the intent of this line `dataGrid.DataSource = data` ?

Comment: thats by mistake, let me remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The WebGrid Helper constructor takes a parameter of type `IEnumerable<object>`.

Ensure your DataTable is enumerable. The easiest way is to use the `AsEnumerable()` extension method. This is in the `System.Data.DataTableExtensions` class.

You'll need to ensure your ViewData object is cast to a DataTable. You can then use that extension method on it.

Unsure if this code actually works:

```
 Dim grid As New WebGrid((DirectCast(ViewData("grid"), DataTable)).AsEnumerable())
```

Comment: No it didn't work, it says asenumerable is not member of System.Data.DataTable